# Android on touch event circle expand

Tags: java, android, shapes, touch-event

I'm looking for a code to do something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9_6rby5fLs

I think it use a view but the problem is how "expand" that circles on thouch event. I can't find anything like that.. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should define a custom view with a circle on canvas that starts expanding at the coordinates you get from the touch events.

Comment: Yes but i can't find anything about expanding coordinates :( have you got some code?

Comment: Do you want how many circles? Like in the animation? You can redesign your circle with new radio size.

Comment: Everytime you touch on the screen it would create a circle.. It could be more interesting that every circle has a different color but it's not important.. for now i need the base like in the example.. Can you?

Comment: Ok I will try to provide you an example but now I'm a bit busy. Start with that example and try to figure it out. As soon as I have some time I will try to implement a solution that suits your needs :). Check out this link: http://adanware.blogspot.de/2012/11/android-creating-custom-view-circle.html